# Hibernate unknown column

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to get the day month and year of `s.eventTime` by using:

```
DAY(s.eventTime) as theDay, MONTH(s.eventTime) as theMonth, YEAR(s.eventTime) as theYear
```

Then later I use `GROUP BY theYear, theMonth, theDay`

This gives me the error:  `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'theYear' in 'group statement'`

I have used this method before in SQL, and was wondering if it is invalid in HQL? If so, does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use aliases on columns. Refer to them by their name. Like on this example from 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping

```
select cat
from Cat cat
    join cat.kittens kitten
group by cat.id, cat.name, cat.other, cat.properties
having avg(kitten.weight) > 100
order by count(kitten) asc, sum(kitten.weight) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't cast `day()`, `month()`, or `year()` with `as` so instead I made my selects like:

```
DAY(s.eventTime), MONTH(s.eventTime), YEAR(s.eventTime)
```

Then grouped the same way with:

```
GROUP BY DAY(s.eventTime), MONTH(s.eventTime), YEAR(s.eventTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) such as `second(...), minute(...), hour(...), day(...), month(...), and year(...)` can only be used in the where clause.

If you need to execute a query that cannot be produced via HQL you can always make a view in your database and map the view as an entity with Hibernate.  It works the same way as a table.